# Implementation of Strategy Pattern in JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the *Calculation.js* file, *CalculationStrategy.js*, and *CalculationStrategyB.js*.

I want to implement the **Strategy Pattern** to these files. However, when I used **Jest** to test the files. I have an error that `this.stragtegy.doOperation is not a function`.

I did follow the tutorial to implement the **Strategy Pattern** by using the `Calculation` file as a base but I don't know why this happens.

*Calculation.js*

```
class Calculation {
constructor(a, b, op) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.op = op;
    this.stragtegy = null;
}

static Create(a, b, op){
    return new Calculation(a, b, op);
}

 GetResults() {
    return this.op(this.a,this.b)
}
addOperationToName(fn){
    return function(name){
        const operation = name + ' is an operation';
        return fn(operation);
    }
}

sayOperation(name){
    return name;
}

obtainStructor(){
    return this.a +' '+ this.b;
}

set strategy(stragtegy){
    this.stragtegy = stragtegy;
}

doOperation(){
    return this.stragtegy.doOperation();
}
}
module.exports = Calculation;
```

*CalculationStrategy.js*

```
class CalculationStrategy{
doAction(){
    return 'This is Calculation Strategy 1';
}
}
module.exports = CalculationStrategy;
```

CalculationStrategyB.js

```
class CalculationStrategyB{
doAction(){
    return 'This is Calculation Strategy 2';
}
}
module.exports = CalculationStrategyB;
```

*CalculationStrategy.test.js*

```
const calculation = require('../src/models/Calculation');
const calculationStrategy = require('../src/CalculationStrategy');
const calculationStrategyB = require('../src/CalculationStrategyB');
const Product = require('../src/Operations/Product');

test('Test Strategy of Calculation', () => {
//I need to test the get results function
let op = Product;
let customCalculation = new calculation(1,2, op);
const strategy = new calculationStrategy();
const strategyB = new calculationStrategyB();
customCalculation.stragtegy = strategy;
expect(customCalculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 1');
customCalculation.stragtegy = strategyB;
expect(customCalculation.doOperation()).toBe('This is Calculation Strategy 2');
});
```

Comment: "by using the Calculation file as a base" You don't extend the Calculation class or pass an instance of it to the other classes, how could it possibly know about Calculation's methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Strategy** classes don't have `doOperation` method but `doAction`.

So change the same in your `Calculation's` `doOperation` method, like so :-

```
doOperation(){
    return this.stragtegy.doAction();
}
```